# From flask-login import breaks deployment of test app in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm a real beginner and I need to better myself.

Running a test app in Google app engine,
via google cloud platform
using cloud shell editor and terminal
yields a nice static test website. Everything works fine,
but when I add the following little code to the main.py file and deploy:

```
from flask_login import LoginManager
```

then the site crashes I think i.e. the site displays:

502 Bad Gateway

---

```
  nginx
```

This was unexpected because
the following code is on the main.py file
when it is working fine:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, request, url_for, render_template
```

Why does from flask work fine, but from flask-login does not?

Since I'm a real beginner I thought I had to change the requirements.txt file,
but, if it is not used anyways in app engine deployment, just in local testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `requirements.txt` **is used** by the App Engine.
It specifies the list of dependencies, that are used in the application. Locally and also during the App Engine Deployment. App Engine cannot guess otherwise, which dependencies it should install.

So you need to add `Flask-Login` (https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Login/) to the `requirements.txt` (with or without version), and then you can import the library in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Python 2 Apps don't use `requirements.txt` file. For Python 2 Apps, you upload your `lib` folder (where you've installed all of your requirements) as part of your deployment process.

Python 3 Apps use `requirements.txt` file. Unlike Python 2 Apps, your library or virtual env shouldn't be deployed (uploaded to Production during deployment). To run your App, Google App Engine reads the contents of your `requirements.txt file`, installs it and then runs your App. This means the file must contain the list of all external libraries needed to run your App

Comment: Thank you NoCommandLine, your answer also helped and solved the problem, but I can only mark one of them, so I had to mark the first one.